# How to fix "Strings inside 'values-ne/strings.xml' file not recognized by play store."

Tags: android, localization

My dual language app is working fine while I run the play store. But,after uploading it in play store, only English language is supported but not the other language.

I have two string files values/strings.xml and values-ne/strings.xml. The app is working file while i run the source code. But once i upload it to the play store and download from there, file inside values-ne/strings.xml is not parsed and my app supports only English language.

```
public static void setLocale(Context ctx, String languageToLoad) {
        Resources resources = ctx.getResources();
        Locale locale;
        if(languageToLoad.equals(AppConstants.LOCALE_ENGLISH)) {
            locale=new Locale(AppConstants.LOCALE_ENGLISH);
        }else{
            locale=new Locale(AppConstants.LOCALE_NEPALI);
        }
        Configuration configuration = resources.getConfiguration();
        configuration.setLocale(locale);
        ctx.getResources().updateConfiguration(configuration,
                ctx.getResources().getDisplayMetrics());

    }
```

After clicking the "Language Change" option, language of all the strings should be changed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Put this in your project gradle file,  in android block.

```
bundle {
    language {
        enableSplit = false
    }
    density {
        enableSplit = true
    }
    abi {
        enableSplit = true
    }
}
```